# Need a Regex Replace For this Pattern

Tags: html, regex, replace, textmate

I am having trouble figuring out how I could get this regex replace to work. I am using textmate and trying to get this:

```
title="cuba1" (could be any number range from 1-50 and any country name)
```

to be replaced with this:

`data-group="cuba1, cuba" class="cuba`"

I have multiple countries with multiple numbers that may or may not go on a country (cuba1, cuba2, etc) as I am setting these on areas and sometimes I need to have groups of areas. This would allow me to implement them faster without needing to do this by hand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have regexps tried so make yourself so far?

Comment: This is all I have so far. I am in no way a regex guru. I know there needs to be more to this. (?<=title\=")[^]+?(?=")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex:

```
title="(([a-zA-Z]+)\d*)"
```

Replacement:

```
data-group="$1, $2" class="$2"
```

Tested in Notepad++. These constructs are pretty standard though; should work with any regex implementation.

EDIT: Comes with the usual caveat: regular expressions are not a good fit for HTML

Comment: this will capture both the word one and word with digits?

Comment: @Justin: it will now! I only tested with number before. It now works with and without number. However, without number produces data-group="cuba, cuba" class="cuba" which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Actually no, the first and second found items are the same for some reason.

`title="newzealand1"`

With the above regex gets me:

`data-group="newzealand1, newzealand1" class="newzealand1"`

instead of 

`data-group="newzealand1, newzealand" class="newzealand"`

Comment: Try incrementing the group numbers i.e \1, \2 = \2, \3. Sometimes the whole regex is treated as group 1.

Comment: The problem here is that \w matches numbers and the \d is optional. Use this regex instead: 

 title="(([a-zA-Z]+)\d*)"

Comment: Thanks Francis. That was it :)

Comment: `Regex: title="(([a-zA-Z]+)\d*)"`

`Replacement: data-group="$1, $2" class="$2"`

Comment: @Francis - of course! I've cleaned up the post to incorporate all feedback.